# Create a flare effect using CoreAnimation

Tags: swift, core-animation

I was wondering is possible to create something like this flare animation with `UIKit` and most likely with `Core Animation`?

[image]

The only thing similar to this i've used previously was `CAEmitterLayer` and `CAEmitterCell` which cannot make this flare

Answer (score 1):

Yes any animation is doable with enough patience.  You can draw a single pixel on the screen and you can specify the color/opacity.

There is absolutely nothing preventing you from using Lines, Bezier paths, or any other method to draw a flare effect.

If you consider the flare effect it is mostly a series of partially opaque lines of different length super-imposed on top of each other.  The center with more "light" has more of the lines overlapping while the edges have fewer until none.

Might take you a few hours fiddling with it to get the desired effect but it's definitely doable.